# ASP.NET RequiredFieldValidator : How can i bind value to " InitialValue " property?

Tags: asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator, html-select

I have the following code

```
<div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="testDropDownList" runat="server" ValidationGroup="testValidationGroup">
        <asp:ListItem Value="Choose">[ Select Item ... ]</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="True">Yes</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="False">No</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="testRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" ValidationGroup="testValidationGroup"
        ErrorMessage="*" InitialValue="Choose" ControlToValidate="testDropDownList"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="testButton" runat="server" OnClick="testButton_Click" Text="Button"
        ValidationGroup="testValidationGroup" />
    <br />
</div>
```

in which i validate Dropdownlist by RequiredFieldValidator

If changed the value of **`initialvalue`** property to read from static property in stactic classs .. but it always give me emtpy string in runtime unless this property have the value "Choose" ...

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="testDropDownList" runat="server" ValidationGroup="testValidationGroup">
        <asp:ListItem Value="Choose">[ Select Item ... ]</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="True">Yes</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="False">No</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="testRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" ValidationGroup="testValidationGroup"
        ErrorMessage="*" InitialValue='<%# Util.ChooseValue %>' ControlToValidate="testDropDownList">
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="testButton" runat="server" OnClick="testButton_Click" Text="Button"
        ValidationGroup="testValidationGroup" />
```

**Could Any one help me to know what's the issue in my code ??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please call

```
testRequiredFieldValidator.databind()
```

in page load event and let me know if this is still an issue.

Comment: Actually you are using binding expression (<%# Util.ChooseValue %>) to set initial value for validator and calling databind method is required to set this value.

Answer (score 1):

Set InitialValue of RequiredFieldValidator on page_load event in aspx.cs page.